# Dataflow Template Fails with Incompatible Class Change Error

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to build and deploy a dataflow job using one template from Google's dataflow templates repo. I stripped out the template and took all of it's dependencies that couldn't be resolved through Maven and put them in a local package. The project builds fine on my local machine, but does not on the agent. How do I find the issue?

Error

```
    Error: Could not deploy the dataflow job: error running the dataflow deployment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9090787Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9273920Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9313989Z    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9328707Z    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9525500Z    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9538298Z    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9587717Z    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9594312Z    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9663168Z    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9714926Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9746322Z    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9824281Z    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9829238Z    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9830934Z    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
2022-08-25T18:14:47.9832751Z    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
2022-08-25T18:14:48.0328994Z    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2022-08-25T18:14:48.0350968Z    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022-08-25T18:14:48.0662389Z    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2022-08-25T18:14:48.0665972Z    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

...

Main Class

```
package edu.mayo.mcc.cdh.pipeline;

import static edu.mayo.mcc.cdh.pipeline.teleport.templates.TextToBigQueryStreaming.wrapBigQueryInsertError;

import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.coders.FailsafeElementCoder;
import edu.mayo.mcc.cdh.pipeline.teleport.templates.common.BigQueryConverters.FailsafeJsonToTableRow;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.ErrorConverters;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer.FailsafeJavascriptUdf;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer.JavascriptTextTransformerOptions;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.util.DualInputNestedValueProvider;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.util.DualInputNestedValueProvider.TranslatorInput;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.util.ResourceUtils;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.util.ValueProviderUtils;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.values.FailsafeElement;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryInsertError;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.InsertRetryPolicy;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessageWithAttributesCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Flatten;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionList;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionTuple;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TupleTag;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

...
public class PubSubToBigQuery {

  /** The log to output status messages to. */
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubSubToBigQuery.class);

  /** The tag for the main output for the UDF. */
  public static final TupleTag<FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>> UDF_OUT =
      new TupleTag<FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>>() {};

  /** The tag for the main output of the json transformation. */
  public static final TupleTag<TableRow> TRANSFORM_OUT = new TupleTag<TableRow>() {};

  /** The tag for the dead-letter output of the udf. */
  public static final TupleTag<FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>> UDF_DEADLETTER_OUT =
      new TupleTag<FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>>() {};

  /** The tag for the dead-letter output of the json to table row transform. */
  public static final TupleTag<FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>> TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT =
      new TupleTag<FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>>() {};

  /** The default suffix for error tables if dead letter table is not specified. */
  public static final String DEFAULT_DEADLETTER_TABLE_SUFFIX = "_error_records";

  /** Pubsub message/string coder for pipeline. */
  public static final FailsafeElementCoder<PubsubMessage, String> CODER =
      FailsafeElementCoder.of(PubsubMessageWithAttributesCoder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of());

  /** String/String Coder for FailsafeElement. */
  public static final FailsafeElementCoder<String, String> FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER =
      FailsafeElementCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of());

  /**
   * The {@link Options} class provides the custom execution options passed by the executor at the
   * command-line.
   */
  public interface Options extends PipelineOptions, JavascriptTextTransformerOptions {
    @Description("Table spec to write the output to")
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputTableSpec();

    void setOutputTableSpec(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("Pub/Sub topic to read the input from")
    ValueProvider<String> getInputTopic();

    void setInputTopic(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description(
        "The Cloud Pub/Sub subscription to consume from. "
            + "The name should be in the format of "
            + "projects/<project-id>/subscriptions/<subscription-name>.")
    ValueProvider<String> getInputSubscription();

    void setInputSubscription(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description(
        "This determines whether the template reads from " + "a pub/sub subscription or a topic")
    @Default.Boolean(false)
    Boolean getUseSubscription();

    void setUseSubscription(Boolean value);

    @Description(
        "The dead-letter table to output to within BigQuery in <project-id>:<dataset>.<table> "
            + "format. If it doesn't exist, it will be created during pipeline execution.")
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputDeadletterTable();

    void setOutputDeadletterTable(ValueProvider<String> value);
  }

  /**
   * The main entry-point for pipeline execution. This method will start the pipeline but will not
   * wait for it's execution to finish. If blocking execution is required, use the {@link
   * PubSubToBigQuery#run(Options)} method to start the pipeline and invoke {@code
   * result.waitUntilFinish()} on the {@link PipelineResult}.
   *
   * @param args The command-line args passed by the executor.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);

    run(options);
  }

  /**
   * Runs the pipeline to completion with the specified options. This method does not wait until the
   * pipeline is finished before returning. Invoke {@code result.waitUntilFinish()} on the result
   * object to block until the pipeline is finished running if blocking programmatic execution is
   * required.
   *
   * @param options The execution options.
   * @return The pipeline result.
   */
  public static PipelineResult run(Options options) {

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    CoderRegistry coderRegistry = pipeline.getCoderRegistry();
    coderRegistry.registerCoderForType(CODER.getEncodedTypeDescriptor(), CODER);

    /*
     * Steps:
     *  1) Read messages in from Pub/Sub
     *  2) Transform the PubsubMessages into TableRows
     *     - Transform message payload via UDF
     *     - Convert UDF result to TableRow objects
     *  3) Write successful records out to BigQuery
     *  4) Write failed records out to BigQuery
     */

    /*
     * Step #1: Read messages in from Pub/Sub
     * Either from a Subscription or Topic
     */

    PCollection<PubsubMessage> messages = null;
    if (options.getUseSubscription()) {
      messages =
          pipeline.apply(
              "ReadPubSubSubscription",
              PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                  .fromSubscription(options.getInputSubscription()));
    } else {
      messages =
          pipeline.apply(
              "ReadPubSubTopic",
              PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromTopic(options.getInputTopic()));
    }

    PCollectionTuple convertedTableRows =
        messages
            /*
             * Step #2: Transform the PubsubMessages into TableRows
             */
            .apply("ConvertMessageToTableRow", new PubsubMessageToTableRow(options));

    /*
     * Step #3: Write the successful records out to BigQuery
     */
    WriteResult writeResult =
        convertedTableRows
            .get(TRANSFORM_OUT)
            .apply(
                "WriteSuccessfulRecords",
                BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .withoutValidation()
                    .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                    .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                    .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                    .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                    .to(options.getOutputTableSpec()));

    /*
     * Step 3 Contd.
     * Elements that failed inserts into BigQuery are extracted and converted to FailsafeElement
     */
    PCollection<FailsafeElement<String, String>> failedInserts =
        writeResult
            .getFailedInsertsWithErr()
            .apply(
                "WrapInsertionErrors",
                MapElements.into(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER.getEncodedTypeDescriptor())
                    .via((BigQueryInsertError e) -> wrapBigQueryInsertError(e)))
            .setCoder(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER);

    /*
     * Step #4: Write records that failed table row transformation
     * or conversion out to BigQuery deadletter table.
     */
    PCollectionList.of(
            ImmutableList.of(
                convertedTableRows.get(UDF_DEADLETTER_OUT),
                convertedTableRows.get(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT)))
        .apply("Flatten", Flatten.pCollections())
        .apply(
            "WriteFailedRecords",
            ErrorConverters.WritePubsubMessageErrors.newBuilder()
                .setErrorRecordsTable(
                    ValueProviderUtils.maybeUseDefaultDeadletterTable(
                        options.getOutputDeadletterTable(),
                        options.getOutputTableSpec(),
                        DEFAULT_DEADLETTER_TABLE_SUFFIX))
                .setErrorRecordsTableSchema(ResourceUtils.getDeadletterTableSchemaJson())
                .build());

    // 5) Insert records that failed insert into deadletter table
    failedInserts.apply(
        "WriteFailedRecords",
        ErrorConverters.WriteStringMessageErrors.newBuilder()
            .setErrorRecordsTable(
                ValueProviderUtils.maybeUseDefaultDeadletterTable(
                    options.getOutputDeadletterTable(),
                    options.getOutputTableSpec(),
                    DEFAULT_DEADLETTER_TABLE_SUFFIX))
            .setErrorRecordsTableSchema(ResourceUtils.getDeadletterTableSchemaJson())
            .build());

    return pipeline.run();
  }

  /**
   * If deadletterTable is available, it is returned as is, otherwise outputTableSpec +
   * defaultDeadLetterTableSuffix is returned instead.
   */
  private static ValueProvider<String> maybeUseDefaultDeadletterTable(
      ValueProvider<String> deadletterTable,
      ValueProvider<String> outputTableSpec,
      String defaultDeadLetterTableSuffix) {
    return DualInputNestedValueProvider.of(
        deadletterTable,
        outputTableSpec,
        new SerializableFunction<TranslatorInput<String, String>, String>() {
          @Override
          public String apply(TranslatorInput<String, String> input) {
            String userProvidedTable = input.getX();
            String outputTableSpec = input.getY();
            if (userProvidedTable == null) {
              return outputTableSpec + defaultDeadLetterTableSuffix;
            }
            return userProvidedTable;
          }
        });
  }

  /**
   * The {@link PubsubMessageToTableRow} class is a {@link PTransform} which transforms incoming
   * {@link PubsubMessage} objects into {@link TableRow} objects for insertion into BigQuery while
   * applying an optional UDF to the input. The executions of the UDF and transformation to {@link
   * TableRow} objects is done in a fail-safe way by wrapping the element with it's original payload
   * inside the {@link FailsafeElement} class. The {@link PubsubMessageToTableRow} transform will
   * output a {@link PCollectionTuple} which contains all output and dead-letter {@link
   * PCollection}.
   *
   * <p>The {@link PCollectionTuple} output will contain the following {@link PCollection}:
   *
   * <ul>
   *   <li>{@link PubSubToBigQuery#UDF_OUT} - Contains all {@link FailsafeElement} records
   *       successfully processed by the optional UDF.
   *   <li>{@link PubSubToBigQuery#UDF_DEADLETTER_OUT} - Contains all {@link FailsafeElement}
   *       records which failed processing during the UDF execution.
   *   <li>{@link PubSubToBigQuery#TRANSFORM_OUT} - Contains all records successfully converted from
   *       JSON to {@link TableRow} objects.
   *   <li>{@link PubSubToBigQuery#TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT} - Contains all {@link FailsafeElement}
   *       records which couldn't be converted to table rows.
   * </ul>
   */
  static class PubsubMessageToTableRow
      extends PTransform<PCollection<PubsubMessage>, PCollectionTuple> {

    private final Options options;

    PubsubMessageToTableRow(Options options) {
      this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    public PCollectionTuple expand(PCollection<PubsubMessage> input) {

      PCollectionTuple udfOut =
          input
              // Map the incoming messages into FailsafeElements so we can recover from failures
              // across multiple transforms.
              .apply("MapToRecord", ParDo.of(new PubsubMessageToFailsafeElementFn()))
              .apply(
                  "InvokeUDF",
                  FailsafeJavascriptUdf.<PubsubMessage>newBuilder()
                      .setFileSystemPath(options.getJavascriptTextTransformGcsPath())
                      .setFunctionName(options.getJavascriptTextTransformFunctionName())
                      .setSuccessTag(UDF_OUT)
                      .setFailureTag(UDF_DEADLETTER_OUT)
                      .build());

      // Convert the records which were successfully processed by the UDF into TableRow objects.
      PCollectionTuple jsonToTableRowOut =
          udfOut
              .get(UDF_OUT)
              .apply(
                  "JsonToTableRow",
                  FailsafeJsonToTableRow.<PubsubMessage>newBuilder()
                      .setSuccessTag(TRANSFORM_OUT)
                      .setFailureTag(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT)
                      .build());

      // Re-wrap the PCollections so we can return a single PCollectionTuple
      return PCollectionTuple.of(UDF_OUT, udfOut.get(UDF_OUT))
          .and(UDF_DEADLETTER_OUT, udfOut.get(UDF_DEADLETTER_OUT))
          .and(TRANSFORM_OUT, jsonToTableRowOut.get(TRANSFORM_OUT))
          .and(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT, jsonToTableRowOut.get(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT));
    }
  }

  /**
   * The {@link PubsubMessageToFailsafeElementFn} wraps an incoming {@link PubsubMessage} with the
   * {@link FailsafeElement} class so errors can be recovered from and the original message can be
   * output to a error records table.
   */
  static class PubsubMessageToFailsafeElementFn
      extends DoFn<PubsubMessage, FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
      PubsubMessage message = context.element();
      context.output(
          FailsafeElement.of(message, new String(message.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }
  }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.mayo.mcc.cdh</groupId>
    <artifactId>df-pubsub-to-bq-lad</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <beam.version>2.35.0</beam.version>

        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-exec-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-exec-plugin.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.2.0</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.2.4</maven-shade-plugin.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.30</slf4j.version>
        <re2j.version>1.6</re2j.version>
        <autovalue.annotations.version>1.7.4</autovalue.annotations.version>
        <autovalue.version>1.7.4</autovalue.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>edu.mayo.mcc.cdh.pipeline.PubSubToBigQuery</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
              Configures `mvn package` to produce a bundled jar ("fat jar") for runners
              that require this for job submission to a cluster.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-bundled-${project.version}</finalName>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-exec-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.re2j/re2j -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.re2j/re2j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.re2j</groupId>
            <artifactId>re2j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>[1.6.0, 1.9.9)</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--
          By default, the starter project has a dependency on the Beam DirectRunner
          to enable development and testing of pipelines. To run on another of the
          Beam runners, add its module to this pom.xml according to the
          runner-specific setup instructions on the Beam website:
            http://beam.apache.org/documentation/#runners
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
            <version>${autovalue.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-value-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${autovalue.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.datastore/datastore-v1-proto-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.datastore</groupId>
            <artifactId>datastore-v1-proto-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you need `google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all`? Sounds like that is a really old dependency, which might be bringing wrong versions of asm/cglib.

Comment: I think you figured it out, thank you! I removed the dependency and got past that initial error

Comment: If you are not using the template as template, remove the `ValueProvider` and just use the plain type wrapped by the `ValueProvider`. Value providers are futures that were handy for templates, as the java code is executed when the template is created, and the values of the options are only available at runtime.